# Data Stream in Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

This may not be a very specific question, but any help or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  I am trying to make a shoes app for myself that will display stock quotes, I'm thinking ahead and the issue I run into is that I would like to have streaming quotes.  I can grab this data from any finance site, and that isn't the issue, but what I am concerned about is how to update the view in the Shoes app.  Can anyone lead me in the right direction to creating an app that will update text in my app every X seconds, or possibly a daemon that does it continuously.  Literally any help is appreciated, as you can probably tell from the question, I definitely need some help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are interested in [Timers](http://shoesrb.com/manual/Timers.html). They let you call procs basing on the interval given.

The good starting point is the code of [clock example](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/blob/develop/samples/good-clock.rb).

```
shoes -m
```

in command line will start `shoes` in help mode.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, this is perfect for what I need!